# What is the meaning of "holding Up" in this context?

Tags: vocabulary, phrasal-verbs

What is the meaning of "holding Up" in this context?

This is the title of [an article](https://www.pressreader.com/usa/san-diego-union-tribune-sunday/20220220/282381222983710):

> 4 BED, 3 BATH, NO GARAGE DOOR: THE WOES HOLDING UP HOME BUILDING

I'm having difficulty in understand what exactly the idea "holding Up" is trying to convey

Comment: Did you look up the phrasal verb "to hold up"?  That seems like it might fit.

Comment: Meaning 2 [at wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hold_up)

Comment: The context here is a listing of a house for sale.

Comment: Meaning 2 from: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hold_up? So rewriting the sentence using this definition from wiktionary meaning 2 would be: 4 bed, 3 bath, no garage door: the woes  DETAINING home building"  OR "4 bed, 3 bath, no garage door: the woesIMPEDING  home building" does those ever make sense?

Comment: to hold  up = to delay

Comment: @FeliniusRex The context is the headline of an article about home building, though part of the title mimics a listing

Answer (score 4):

This is a headline in the New York Times about a shortage of garage doors, which is one of the unusual woes (or problems) affecting home builders in the USA at this time, and holding up (delaying) the completion and sale of homes. The article below the headline makes this very clear.

[image]